# Windows 2003 Unresponsive on VMWare Server 2.0

Tags: windows-server-2003, vmware-server

I have had an installation of Windows 2003 ColdFusion and MS SQL 2000 running on VMWare Server 2. It has run perfectly for over a year. Now about every other day I have to restart the vmware service because the Windows server is unresponsive and unreachable. There is nothing in the event log on the Windows server and there is nothing of note.

I can not figure out how to diagnose what is going on.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Josh

Answer (score 1):

Unresponsive as in the VMWare console won't come up, or it comes up but Windows isn't responding to input (we've had systems that are network unreachable but you can see at the console view they locked up)?

Can you keep the session open at the console with something like process explorer or process monitor from sysinternals running to see if anything shows up just as it's locking up?

Does chkdsk in the virtual session (or on the host) find anything amiss?

Something obvious but sometimes needs to be checked-disk space? Nothing about low disk space showing up at all, or anything that could indicate a runaway process causing virtual memory to go nuts?

Malware check (spybot, lavasoft's utility, etc.) indicate nothing unusual? Antivirus up to date and a full scan finds nothing?

Comment: I've also seen the case where VMs were network unreachable, until you went to the console and moved the mouse! It was like it had gone to sleep or something.